# Has or had + would have been?

Tags: conditionals

> If it has happened, it would have been horrible.
>
> If it had happened, it would have been horrible.

Are both correct? Can I use "has" and "would have been" like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If it has happened* implies *it* may have happened, but you do not know it (yet). This sentence could be a so-called [firstconditional_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#First_conditional).  (see link for examples):

> "First conditional" or "conditional I" refers to a pattern used in predictive conditional sentences, i.e. those that concern consequences of a probable future event

*If it had happened*  implies *it* did not happen. This sentence is a so-called [*third conditional*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Third_conditional) (see the link for examples):

> "Third conditional" or "conditional III" is a pattern used to refer to hypothetical situations in a past time frame, generally counterfactual (or at least presented as counterfactual).

Since you are following up with *it would have been horrible*, I'm guessing you want it to mean (just adding this for clarity, the latter sentence, which has the same meaning, is more pleasant to read / hear in conversation):

> If it would have happened, it would have been horrible.

So you could phrase it as (the two sentences in the orange background mean the same), so you would go with the second one of the proposed options:

> If it had happened, it would have been horrible.

Comment: *"If it would have happened, it would have been horrible."* is non-standard English, and grates on many people's ears, even though several dialects in the U.S. use it.

Comment: @PeterShor I agree, however, I think it helps explain the meaning of the second sentence (because the two are equivalent, and I think the first is easier to understand). Edited to point this out in the answer.

Comment: Can I use the first sentence at all? Someone told me that I can’t use “has” and “would have been” together, although you stated that it’s first conditional. What he meant is that only “had” plus “would have been” is considered a conditional sentence.

Comment: The first sentence does not sound correct to me. I cannot say for sure that the combination of _has_ and _would have been_ is wrong per se, but I cannot think of a proper example in which they are used together correctly either.